# How to apply jpeg image rotation not with Exif header mention of this rotation, but with recomputing the data on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, images, jpeg, exif

Is this option available somewhere? I have a lot of scanned data that has reorientation from landscape to portrait in Exif files, but not in jpeg data itself. And I can't use some file uploaders like Froala due to this issue, files are not correctly processed.

Link to froala issues:

https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/3670
https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/1693

So any ideas how to explicitly rotate the jpeg image data with some tools, anb better allowing the batch mode?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you would like to batch-rotate images based on their EXIF data so that they will keep their orientation when displayed by viewers that do not use the EXIF for display?

Comment: @harrymc right, exactly!

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure that any of the answers from the suggested questions feets the best solution for Windows 10